# Is there a maximum number of pages when printing in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, print-preview

I've developed a page that shows a lot of data(~100 pages), but print preview cuts the amount of pages off when it hits 86 pages.

If I change the scale down in print preview properties, more data is shown on the page and the number of pages decreases.

Does chrome have a page limit, or data limit that can be shown in print preview? Or is the way the page is being rendered cause issues with print preview(angular repeating divs)?

Edit:

Tried this in Firefox and Firefox prints all pages when saving as a PDF, chrome does not.

Comment: I have the same problem with Chrome. Firefox worked fine for me as well.

Comment: Having the same issue. Adjusting the size of text in my project using @media(print) does not increase the amount of data Chrome displays for print (so it doesn't seem to be a 'page-limit' issue, but maybe a data/memory issue?). Firefox working OK for me too

Comment: I can't empirically find a clear limit in Chrome v79. I was able to make a 1k-page PDF in several seconds, but I stopped waiting for a 5k-page PDF after about 15 minutes. This was with very simple content to try to figure out if there's a true page limit, vs. something like a data content limit.