# How to avoid truncation of Jupyter notebooks printed from Colab using Chrome?

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I use Google Colab and run Jupyter notebooks of size10-20 pages with Python code.
The output on the screen is ok and complete, but when I print the notebook from inside Chrome then the notebook often get truncated. Sometimes already around 10 pages.

Further the printed version sometimes get overlap of  diagrams and code and useless.

How to avoid these problems?
Do I really need the package nbconvert for this?
(I have no problems printing notebooks when run  locally, only remotely with Colab)

Comment: Not following where you are printing from? You say, "I have no problems printing notebooks when run locally".  If you've run it on Colab, then why cannot you download it and print it locally? Yes, you need `jupyter nbconvert` for this as it handles generating the static forms of the Jupyter `.ipynb` file. I'll add though that also as you say run locally is better than that is a subtle hint to steer your use towards relying on using & supporting open source **actual** Jupyter and not relying on a large company that forked a very old version of Jupyter & customized it extensively ...

Comment: <continued> and has a poor track record of keeping things updated or adding more modern conveniences **actual** Jupyter currently has. I could also mention they have a poor track record of retiring things others find useful, hence [the Google Graveyard](https://killedbygoogle.com/). The sooner you become independent, the longer your Jupyter experience will be smooth sailing into the future. As for the current issue, is it reproducible with smaller notebook files? Is it consistent with the long ones or only with certain code that maybe customizes CSS?

Comment: Well, I develop my notebook locally on my computer using standard open Jupyter notebook. Then wen the notebook is ok, then I copy (manually) cell by cell into a Colab (Jupyter) notebook. The first cells of the Colab notebook includes also import of miniconda and some packages that I have on my local machine. The resulting Colab (Jupyter) notebook run is fine using Google Colab. All pages thre. But when I shall print the Colab (Jupyter) notebook it gets truncated. It is very reproducible. Here is some limit in Chrom 20 pages and I am ok with that. The true local Jupyter notebook prints ok.

Comment: Did you try a different browser? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44117156/8508004) said for a different large file that Chrome was messed up on, Firefox seemed good.

Comment: Among my peers, Chrome is seen as "better". Further since the problem seems related to Google Colab interaction with the browser, it is likely better using Google Chrome. But, sure I can try Firefox and see if the problem is there too. I do that tomorrow.

Comment: Actually, both Firefox and Safari manage to print out all pages (to PDF) and there is no mixup of diagrams and code, either. But here is a new problem! Now the numbering of the cells does not show up at all. Same problem for both Firefox and Safari.  Is here some setting in Firefox related to left margin that need adjustment, or what?

Comment: Now I even tried Microsoft Edge and get both truncation AND loss of left margin with cell number. Seems either hope for Google to update Colab notebook to be on par with Jupyter notebook in this respect, or start to use package nbconvert.

Comment: I doubt that Google doing anything to Colab will help here. Your investigation and the link I referenced suggest this is caused by the browser limitations, I think.

Comment: But, Chrome the other browsers works well when notebooks are presented to the screen. Perhaps more difficult to print a screen  (to PDF or something else, than I understand. But in case of native (and current) Jupyter notebooks what you see on screen you can print. Indicates to me a possibility that the problem is the Colab notebook format, somehow. But here still interest in package nbconvert and I should perhaps start to learn and use that?

Comment: Great point! I forgot about the point it works in Chrome locally & was hoping it was simpler. When you use Jupyter on your own machine, using the menu to 'export' the notebook is using `jupyter nbconvert` behind the scenes.  By the way, is there any chance you are involving a PDF as your investigation of printing? Looking into whether this old extension (so I wouldn't recommend it now) may help you, [this note](https://github.com/betatim/notebook-as-pdf#use-it) at the bottom about Mac Preview not being compatible with attachments, made me wonder if that tech mismatch could be involved? ...

Comment: <continued> Pertinent part: "You will have to use Acrobat Reader to see the attachment to your PDF. Preview on OSX can not display PDF attachments."

Comment: Here is no PDF attached. The Python cells generate diagrams though using Matplotlib. Here is also a png-file brought in see section 1, but the "printing to PDF problem" persist if I exclude it. Below Github ref to both the local generated notebook PDF and the Colab generated one https://github.com/janpeter19/BPL_CHO_Fedbatch/blob/main/BPL_CHO_Fedbatch.pdf https://github.com/janpeter19/BPL_CHO_Fedbatch/blob/main/BPL_CHO_Fedbatch_colab.pdf

Comment: I'm even more confused by what you added and are saying in the last comment. Everything we have been talking about should be after the notebook has been run and so Matplotlib isn't involved. The PDFs that get made can be using attachments in how they get made. It was a suggestion to look into that. But since you are now sharing `.ipynb` files and corresponding PDFs. You should make an update in your original post to show at least one specific example what you are referring to in these two pdf files.  And don't rely on GitHub to do this. I'm not sure if you know but GitHub doesn't fully ....

Comment: <continued> render static notebooks. [nbviewer](https://nbviewer.org/ is more reliable with viewing the static `.ioynb` files hosted on GitHub, or anywhere on the internet. It is just a service you can point at your notebooks hosted online. In the case of GitHub hosted `.ipynb` files, the pattern of the resulting URL is consistent so you can make them without even using the form once you know. Anyway, don't rely on GitHub to let you know what is really going on and only think of anything it shows as a preview. Anyway, what you've added are the same notebooks as far as I see and they are ...

Comment: <continued> very long so please highlight some examples of what you mean with some images that make it clear the corresponding parts.

Comment: Sorry, try to explain last comment better below.

The first PDF is made from a notebook made locally (in Windows environment) 

The second PDF is made from a notebook in Colab (in Linux environment)
And to have the notebook run you need to first install miniconda and  a few packages. 

I keep the first PDF in Github since good just for reference. 

The problem with the second PDF made in Colab compared with the locally made first PDF is

1. There is no numbering the cells
2. The notebook is truncated at the end after just two bullet points in the summary compared the first PDF

Comment: Another observation I just made is that Google Colab has since September last year slightly changed behaviour 
so that truncation of notebooks  when printed  to PDF now occurs  for otherwise identical settings. The lack
of cell numbering was there before. Here is since September a change of conda from 23.7.4 to 23.11.0 though
and likely some differences in current packages at lower level, but hard to believe it matters. 

It seems to be necessary to introduce nbconvert for Colab notebooks.
I wish Google could just fix the matter though. The problem likely affect a lot of people